# Android Camera API 2 Auto Focus on Front Camera

Tags: android, camera, autofocus, front-camera, camera-api

I am working with Camera API 2 in Android and trying to apply the auto focus feature. The auto focus is working fine with back camera but not the front camera.

(I am using Android 5.1 and 6.0 devices)

Detail:

This is the trigger to start auto focus:

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
```

and this is the CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback

```
 Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
```

The value of afState is always 0 (INACTIVE) if I use front camera. But with the back camera, that value is changed from 2 (CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_FOCUSED - trying to focus) to 4 (CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED when focus successful) or 5 (CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED when focus unsuccessful).

Do you guys have any idea about why I can not use auto focus on front camera?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe your front camera does not have autofocus. 
To check this you can execute

```
int[] afAvailableModes = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AF_AVAILABLE_MODES);
```

If the only available AF mode is `CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF`, then it means your camera has fixed focus lens. And according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#CONTROL_AF_STATE) when `android.control.afMode` is `AF_MODE_OFF` or `AF_MODE_EDOF` the state will always remain `INACTIVE`.